# Reading in multiple txt files, i can step through and see each being processed but nothing ends up on the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, import, text-files

```
       OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) to Import", `
                         `MultiSelect:=True)
       For cntr = 1 To Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
             Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(cntr))
        
           TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
           Workbooks(1).Activate
           Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Add
           ActiveSheet.Paste
        
           TextFile.Close
        Next cntr
```

Comment: Try `textfile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy`

Comment: the spreadsheets open under (personal.xlsb) under the Microsoft Excel Objects folder when I open the spreadsheets. Anyone know why it ends up there and not on the active sheet as additional tabs

Comment: Where is the code located ? Is it in the same workbook that you want to  add sheets ?

Comment: I was running it from the editor. I have a couple different Projects and am running from the first one and the data ends up in the second

Comment: You need to replace `Workbooks(1)` with the specific workbook you want the sheets added to.

Comment: Thank you.  If there are 2 projects open, how does the system determine which workbook is active?

Comment: Using the property [ActiveWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook).  Since you are opening and closing text files as workbooks the ActiveWorkbook will be changed by the script. Better to assign the workbook to a reference when you open it.

Comment: awesome idea. So I can then track by  the name. It would make the code easier to read.